# Programmatically push to new page with cell ID being used as navigation bar name

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a UITableViewController with a bunch of cells. When I click on one of the cells in the table I want to be able to go a new page and the navigation title to be the name of the cell clicked on.

The first page with the table view controller is named "jobList" and the new page is named "jobInfo".

I am using Firebase so it needs to reference the cell ID that has been stored in firebase (not sure this matters for what I am trying to do, but thought I would mention that).

Here is the code I am using to go to the new tableview from the cell ID.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let job = self.jobs[indexPath.row]
    let jobInfo = page_jobInfo()
    show(jobInfo, sender: job)
    }
```

and on the new page I am using this code before my Super View Did Load

```
var job: Job? {
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = job?.jobName
    }
}
```

my dictionary looks like this

```
class Job: NSObject {
var id: String?
var jobBrand: String?
var jobName : String?
var jobLevel : String?
//var director : String?
init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
    self.jobBrand = dictionary["jobBrand"] as? String
    self.jobName = dictionary["jobName"] as? String
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what your question/problem is. What is happening?  What do you want to happen?

Comment: So the problem I have is when I tap on a cell on my tableviewcontroller I am linked to a new page. The navigation bar title at the top of the new page is blank. I want the navigation bar title to take the same name as the cell name I have just tapped on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. You are saying:

```
let job = self.jobs[indexPath.row]
let jobInfo = page_jobInfo()
show(jobInfo, sender: job)
```

You are artificially creating a variable called `job` and claiming falsely that it is the `sender` in your call to `show(_:sender:)`. That is a false claim — `self` is the `sender` — and in any case, it has *no effect* on the `job` property in the `jobInfo` view controller.

If you want to change the `job` property of the `jobInfo` view controller, *you* must change it, explicitly. For example:

```
let jobInfo = page_jobInfo()
jobInfo.job = // whatever you want `job` to be
show(jobInfo, sender: self)
```

Comment: Thanks matt, thats working now using your latest code - I just added self.jobs[indexPath.row] to the second line:

let jobInfo = page_jobInfo()
jobInfo.job = self.jobs[indexPath.row]
show(jobInfo, sender: self)

("+1, great answer!");